# Mongo search within array of tuple objects

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm using meteor(mongodb) as a backend and I'm trying to query a collection that holds the data this way:

```
{ 
    "name" : "Some name",
    "data" : [
        { 
          "0" : { "type" : "textInput", "value" : "Text", }, 
          "1" : { "type" : "textInput", "value" : "Text", }, 
          "2" : { "type" : "userInput", "value" : {
                  "userIds" : [ ... "Some mongo objectIds" ... ], 
              }, 
          }, 
          "3" : { "type" : "textInput", "value" : "Some text", } 
        },
        {
          "0" : { "type" : "textInput", "value" : "some text", }, 
          "1" : { "type" : "textInput", "value" : "some text", }, 
        }
    ], 
}
```

`data` field can hold any number of objects, each object is a map from number to object with `type` and `value` fields.
Specifically, I would like to find all the documents that has a `userInput` and hold a specific userId (mongo objectId). How can I do it with this data structure?

In this example I can look for `"Some mongo objectIds"` to find this document (first object of data, index 2).

Comment: With this structure you cannot really search it effectively since you have "named keys" and MongoDB needs to know the direct path at which to search. You would be better of changing the structure so that the "index" was actually represented within the array itself.

Comment: As an example `"data"` should instead be like `[{ "index": 0, "type" : "textInput", "value" : "Text" }, { "index": 1, "type" : "textInput", "value" : "Text" }]` and so on. This allows you to query via `.find({ "data": { "$elemMatch": { "type": "userInput", "userIds": userId  } } })`, which is an easy form to use. Without it the only available methods require a full collection scan and also JavaScript evaluation to traverse the paths unless you are using a latest MongoDB 3.4. And it's still a "full collection scan" even "if" we can avoid the JavaScript evaluation.

Comment: Point being, Change the structure since it simply does not work with the general "database concept" of searching by "values" as opposed to "searching by keys" which you presently have. The only other alternate approach is to specify "every possible index key" via an `$or` expression. Which is almost equally as taxing and cumbersome to construct as a query, if not practically impossible. Make you life easier and realize this structure does not work for the sort of queries you need to do.